# Positioning for popovers in Twitter Bootstrap 2.0?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm experimenting with [Twitter Bootstrap 2.0](http://markdotto.com/bs2/docs/index.html) and want to use the [popovers](http://markdotto.com/bs2/docs/javascript.html#popovers). I've got everything working fine, but regardless of which 'placement' I specify, they show up about 50px or so lower than they should, as though there's an offset somewhere.

Here are my  options:

```
$(function() {
    $(".pop").popover({ animation: true, placement: 'right', trigger: 'hover' })
});
```

I've tried specifying `'placement: -50'`, `'placement: [0,-50]'`, `'position: -50'`, and `'offset: -50'` just to see if I could get anything to happen, but none of these settings affect anything. I've also tried editing my copy of bootstrap.css to change the default `'top'` position from `'0'` to `'-50px'` but that did not do anything either. There are plenty of previous questions that should help [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/mT76T/17/), but I still get the same results in my site.

This is what my popover looks like if I paste in the exact code from the demo page:
[image]

Am I just missing something stupid? Why is the one on the demo page showing up with the little arrow pointing directly at the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out, I had added a top margin to the body and that was throwing everything off.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but can't seem to find any margin being applied that might throw it off. Would you have any more information on your solution?

Comment: I had a similar problem when I tried to wrap my `<a rel="popover" ... >`tag around a div instead of putting it inside, which is bad practice anyway. Maybe create a new question and put up your code so others can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to show image inside popover and i had the same problem. The Solution was to set Height and Width to that image.